# Protect Cells after data Entry, need to enter weight, record time of entry in specific format, compare value, and set counter

Tags: excel, vba, list, range

```
   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="123"

 Target.Locked = True
Dim tasksheet As Worksheet

Dim i As Integer

Dim T2 As Integer
Set tasksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Lr = tasksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To Lr

If tasksheet.Cells(i, "A").Value <> "" And tasksheet.Cells(i, "B").Value = "" Then
tasksheet.Cells(i, "B").Value = Time

tasksheet.Cells(i, "B").NumberFormat = "hh:mm"

tasksheet.Cells(i, "A").Font.ColorIndex = 5

End If

 If tasksheet.Cells(i, "A") < 18.9 Then

                   T2 = T2 + 1

            tasksheet.Cells(i, "A").Font.ColorIndex = 3

        End If
Next

 Cells(5, 10).Value = T2

ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="123"

End Sub
```

I keep Receiving Error:

> Run time Error 1004 : Unable to set number format property out of Range Class

Would you please assist, I have a little VB knowledge.
Thank you in advance

Comment: What line gives the error?

Comment: tasksheet.Cells(i, "B").NumberFormat = "hh:mm"

Comment: Are you sure the sheet has been unprotected?

Comment: After entry non blank cells are protected but VB error appear with Error 1004

Comment: If I remove Sheet protection, the code runs with no error

Comment: Yes, I have checked, it is unprotected